# Writing Bash script to test C Program

Tags: bash, testing

I am quite new to bash scripting and I am thinking of using it to run few test cases for my C program.
I have my results expected in a file called output.txt

I run my program:

> ./a.out > output_res_gen.txt
>
> diff output_gen.txt output_res_gen.txt

If the program has run correct I get the following difference:

```
10001c10001
< Time: 0.291555
---
> Time: 0.111091
```

(That is time taken to execute the code, which can vary).

I wrote my bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ..
./a.out > ../tests/output_res_gen.txt
diff ../tests/output_gen.txt ../tests/output_res_gen.txt
```

However my code does not execute (./a.out does not run). Also is there a way to find the difference between the 2 files and verify that the only difference is in between the time to execute?

Comment: If `a.out` can't be found by the bash script, you should see an error message like "No such file or directory". If nothing appears to happen, then either your bash script didn't run, of the output goes somewhere you didn't expect. What is the actual output you get when running the bash script?

Comment: @Evert I get diff: ../tests/output_gen.txt: No such file or directory
diff: ../tests/output_res_gen.txt: No such file or directory
These files have not been generated. However output_gen.txt does exist in the tests folder

Comment: `output_gen.txt` (which exists) appear to be your comparison file. It is `output_res_gen.txt` you should be looking for. It appears, however, that the `cd ..` creates some problems. You might consider debugging the script by inserting `echo $(pwd)` at some points.